# socket.io broadcast on api call to everyone except "sender"

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm making an API call from a client to the server, and I don't want to send the message in the websocket as well.

What's the best way for the server to broadcast to all other clients when this happens?

I was thinking maybe to attach the client socketId in the headers, and reading that on the server, and looping over all the connected clients and send them, something like:

```js
Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).forEach((socketId) => {
  if (socketId === socketIdFromHeader) return
  socket.broadcast.to(socketId).emit('message', 'my message');
});
```

I see a couple of problems here:

1. it feels hacky
2. If I have a large scale of connected clients, running a separate function for each of them will be expensive.

Any ideas how'd you go about it?

Thanks!

PS. I'm new to Socket.io and websockets

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that your API connection is completely different from your web socket connection. So if you want to send data to all users but the sender, you should store a map from usersId (any identification you have of users which you have access in both socket.io connection and your API) to users socket id.
for example store the data in redis. to get user in io connection your client can send a token in query string, and then you find the user in your database using this token or decode the user If you are using JWT.

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
    let user = await getUserUsingToken(socket.handshake.query.token);
    await redis.set(user._id, socket.id);
}
```

and in your api get socket id from Redis

```
let sid = await redis.get(user._id);
Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).forEach((socketId) => {
  if (socketId === sid) return
  socket.broadcast.to(socketId).emit('message', 'my message');
});
```

You can store this mapping anywhere you like. I just showed you Redis as an example.

Comment: sound to me that sending the socket id in the header is much simpler

Comment: Yes, you can also do that. in io.on('connection') method send the socketId to the client  using socket.emit('yourSocketId', socket.id) and then your client can send his socketId in API calls inside request header.

Comment: why not just get the socket id in the client on connection? no need to send it from the server

Comment: I don't know if socket id is the same in client and server. but if it is the same that works too. It seems that in newer versions of socket.io they are the same. So it depends on your socket.io version.